# What does y_p :::python do in this (or any) script?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to work through the tutorial by Sebastian Raschka on Feature scaling and I can't get the code below to run because it throws and error with the third line, the one that end in 'python'.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(10,5))

y_p    :::python
    # Standardization

    x = [1,4,5,6,6,2,3]
    mean = sum(x)/len(x)
    std_dev = (1/len(x) * sum([ (x_i - mean)**2 for x_i in x]))**0.5

    z_scores = [(x_i - mean)/std_dev for x_i in x]

    # Min-Max scaling

    minmax = [(x_i - min(x)) / (min(x) - max(x)) for x_i in x]os = [0 for i in range(len(x))]

ax1.scatter(z_scores, y_pos, color='g')
ax1.set_title('Python standardization', color='g')

ax2.scatter(minmax, y_pos, color='g')
ax2.set_title('Python Min-Max scaling', color='g')

ax3.scatter(z_scores_np, y_pos, color='b')
ax3.set_title('Python NumPy standardization', color='b')
The-effect-of-standardization
ax4.scatter(np_minmax, y_pos, color='b')
ax4.set_title('Python NumPy Min-Max scaling', color='b')

plt.tight_layout()

for ax in (ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4):
    ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
    ax.grid()

plt.show()
```

So, what does the y_p  :::python do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is it isn't valid python code.

You should look at the ipython notebook that I believe you got some parts of that code from.

http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/rasbt/pattern_classification/blob/master/preprocessing/about_standardization_normalization.ipynb

The relevant snippet is

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(10,5))

y_pos = [0 for i in range(len(x))]

ax1.scatter(z_scores, y_pos, color='g')
ax1.set_title('Python standardization', color='g')
```

Comment: That is interesting. Actually the code I am using comes from the website: http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_about_feature_scaling.html                but the notebook you link to is much cleaner. Maybe it is there to convert the website to the notebook or something? Anyway, thanks for clearing that up for me. I appreciate it.

Comment: Apparently the HTML export got messed up